# How to read Xml file(which is used as data base ) using javascript or jquery or ajax call.?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I saw one project in which one developer save one XML(as a database) file having some data .And he call that database (XML file) using Jquery or Ajax and used that data in his project .I want to learn that thing .He placed that file on their project.He call database and fetch data from database.Can you please give me an example in jquery how to fetch data?He is making mobile app using jquery and Phonegap .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/some/path/file.xml', function (data) {
    var xmlDoc = $(data);
    // traversing:
    var someChildNodes = xmlDoc.find('section > article');
}
```

Comment: please provide whole example if you have.?